# Can't convert String into integer in ruby/ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to verify if a user exists, and if so, do a password match.

My controller looks like this:

```
def attempt_login
    authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
    if authorized_user
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."
        redirect_to(:action => 'menu')
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password"
        redirect_to(:action => 'login')
    end
end
```

The model looks like:

```
def self.authenticate(username="", password="")
    user = User.find_by_username(username)
    if user && user.password_match?(password)
        return user
    else
        return false
    end
end

def password_match?(password="")
    hashed_password == User.hash_with_salt(password,salt)
end
```

In the process of doing this, I receive the TypeError (Can't convert String into Integer). I suspect the error occurs when I want to set a value for `authorized_user`, but do not know how to approach this issue.

Edit:
My server log is empty. But I can post the Framework Trace:

```
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:23:in `delete'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:23:in `block in clear'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:21:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:21:in `clear'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Bootstrap>'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:420:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

And here is the development.log if it could help:

```
Started POST "/access/attempt_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-27 20:19:19 +0200
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.action_view.debug_rjs will be removed in 3.1, from 3.1 onwards you will need to install prototype-rails to continue to use RJS templates . (called from <top (required)> at G:/Projects/basicsocial/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1)
Processing by AccessController#attempt_login as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jvGVYJEypK9sWoaaa5c2OwzBKmCMX7h7Wp28vBH9wfw=", "username"=>"test88", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log In"}
<-[1m<-[36mSQL (7.0ms)<-[0m  <-[1mdescribe `users_pages`<-[0m
<-[1m<-[35mSQL (2.0ms)<-[0m  SHOW TABLES
<-[1m<-[36mUser Load (0.0ms)<-[0m  <-[1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'test88' LIMIT 1<-[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin
Completed 302 Found in 545ms

TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):
Rendered E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (5.0ms)
Rendered E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (16.0ms)
```

The `salt` variable is what I use to better secure my user's page. This is something that is stored in the database.

Comment: Please post the backtrace (line the error occured on) of the error (must be present in your server log).

Comment: Where are you getting the type error?  By the way, in your `password_match?` function, what is the `salt` variable referring to?  If you need to ever to converting on a variable, just use `.to_i` to convert to Integer and `.to_s` to convert to String

Comment: Looks like your `attempt_login` is working, but the error happens when you are redirecting to your `admin` page, it's probably somewhere in your view or controller for your `admin#index` where you are trying to use a String as an Integer.

Comment: The view or the controller for the admin#index doesn't use anything that tries to use a String or an integer. This is because the controller is empty and the view is html only at the moment.

Comment: @Cobalt, could you post the "Application Trace" as well?

Comment: I would, but the Application Trace is empty, and the framework as well as the full trace are exactly the same

Comment: It does look like the error happens after redirecting. Try taking out the `redirect_to` statements and see if it still happens. Do you have anything in your application controller, routes, or middleware that uses `authorized_user`?

Comment: after removing the `redirect_to` the error persists. The `authorized_user` I use in my controller to verify if the user is already registered. By using the `authenticate` method of my User class I do the verification. This method either returns false or the user object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was nothing wrong with the code. It was probably related to my browsers cache or something of that nature, as it started working the next day. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and spent hours trying to fix it. It turned out that I had left in a method that the tutorial had told me to delete a few videos beforehand:

```
 def self.hash(password="")
   Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
 end
```

In the tutorial, this had been replaced by the methods

```
 def self.make_salt(username="")
   Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Use #{username} with #{Time.now} to make salt")
 end

 def self.hash_with_salt(password="", salt="")
   Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Put #{salt} on the #{password}")
 end
```

Once I commented this method out, the error went away. I still don't understand why that error showed up in the first place. I added a question and more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267484/why-does-this-unused-self-hash-method-cause-a-cant-convert-string-into-integer).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to let you know that i had this problem as well.
The issue was quickly solved but the server showed the error every request afterwards.
Code changes have not been reflected until i restarted the server.

`touch tmp/restart.txt` was not sufficient so i had to restart the server `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` to remove the error message.

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Apr  1 2012 07:14:38

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

$ gem list passenger
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
passenger (3.0.13)

$ bundle exec rails -v
Rails 3.0.7
```