# Why does this unused self.hash method cause a "can't convert String into Integer" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running through the [Lynda Rails 3 tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-on-Rails-3-tutorials/essential-training/55960-2.html). At one point, in a controller called access_controller, we call a method from a model called AdminUser. The original call was:

```
authorized_user = AdminUser.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
```

When I run rails server, open up the browser, and access the appropriate view, I get the error: **TypeError, can't convert String into Integer**

This same question has been asked [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497351/cant-convert-string-into-integer-in-ruby-ruby-on-rails) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048098/user-authentication-trying-to-convert-string-into-integer). The first time, the asker says the problem resolved itself the next day. (I first ran into this 3 days ago, so that has not happened.) The second question has not been answered. I will try to provide much more detail:

The method in the model was:

```
  def self.authenticate(username="", password="")
    user = AdminUser.find_by_username(username)
    if user && user.password_match?(password)
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

When I call this method from the rails console, it works totally fine. Something about calling it from a controller, or trying to get at via the browser, seems to be going wrong (I am relative beginner, so I apologize that I cannot express this thought better). I have since replicated this error with a more simple method in the same AdminUser model:

```
  def self.nothing
    true
  end
```

This still gives me the same error. I then tried calling the self.nothing method from a different controller and action (called pages_controller#show). When I tried to open that up in the browser, I once again got the same error: "can't convert String into Integer"

I then created an identical self.nothing method in my Subject model. When I try to run that method from the show action in pages_controller, it works totally fine. No errors.

So, the same method runs totally fine in rails console, totally fine when I place it in my Subject model, but produces an error when I place it in my AdminUser model.

I then tried to comment out basically everything in sight in my AdminUser model to see if I can make the error go away. I finally was able to. The error was apparently caused by another method:

```
 def self.hash(password="")
   Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
 end
```

I was supposed to have deleted this method a few video lessons ago when we added these other methods:

```
 def self.make_salt(username="")
   Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Use #{username} with #{Time.now} to make salt")
 end

 def self.hash_with_salt(password="", salt="")
   Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Put #{salt} on the #{password}")
 end
```

I never deleted the initial one, but for some reason, it was the one causing the error.

So, my question now is: Why did leaving in that method (which was not being used anywhere) cause this "can't convert String into Integer" error?

Comment: I haven't read very closely but be aware that when Ruby reloads your code, it loads new methods but doesn't delete old ones. You have to do it manually or restart your server.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I don't think that was causing the issue since I restarted many times, but I didn't know that so it is helpful information.

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: The error trace will tell you exactly which line in which file is raising the error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `User.hash` overrides `Object.hash` that should return a `Fixnum`.
You should change it's name for something like `User.make_hash`